# Как сделать, чтобы массив начинался не с 0, а 1 индекса?

Tags: массивы, индексы

Как сделать, чтобы массив начинался не с 0, а 1 индекса?

Comment: В каком языке программирования? с? с++ java?

Comment: А конкретно для чего вам надо?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, про какой язык программирования идёт речь.

Comment: В .NET, например, (но не в C#) поддерживаются массивы с [любым начальным индексом](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Если программируете на С++, то можно переписать действие оператора [ ], но я вам не рекомендую это делать, можете непосредственно вычитать единицу при индексации:

> for (int i=1; i<N; i++){
> cout<<array[i-1]<<endl; }

Answer (score 0):

Свою функцию написать по работе с массивом. В аргументе передаете 1 для обозначения 1-го элемента и внутри хитро меняете на 0, чтобы никто не видел. А в стандартном исполнении никак. Например, в Си имя массива есть указатель на первый элемент, а индекс ноль просто задает смещение относительно начала массива. Нулевое смещение и дает ссылку на первый элемент. Все привязано к технике. А так только свою функцию реализовывать. Ноль слишком раздражает, ну представьте, что это единица, просто пухлая)

Comment: Ну, если с элементами массива работать через указатель, то не просто, **а очень просто**

      int a[10], *my_array = a - 1;
      int i;
 
      for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        my_array[i] = i * 2;

      // проверим
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         printf ("%d : %d (%d : %d)\n", i + 1, my_array[i + 1], i, a[i]);

      
(тщательней изучайте матчасть)

--

@Akbar, откровенно говоря, идея индексировать с 1 -- дурацкая. Мало того, что окружающие Вас будут плохо понимать, но еще и сами будете на самом деле делать больше ошибок, чем при индексировании с 0.

Comment: Чтобы индексы начинались с 1, следует программировать на Бэйсике.

Comment: В паскале/делфи можно задать начальный индекс, какой нужно, хоть 100.

В бейсике на самом деле оно тоже с нуля начинается. Просто нулевой не используется. Хотя бейсики разные бывают.